# Let me change the meetings timing. Which is correct form from the below options

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Let me change the meetings timing.

or

Let me change the meetings timings.

or

Let me change the meetings time.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Adam. We expect people to do a little more research before posting a question. If their research does not help, they should write a specific question and provide details for their research. In this case, you could try to find out what the difference is between time and timing. You could also describe the situation: who is asking the question? are they asking for permission- if so, who from? How many meetings are there?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adjusting the  start time of the meeting, then use:

> Let me change the **meeting time**.

*meeting time* is a noun phrase. If you meant more than one meeting, then:

> Let me change the **meeting times**.